# How to edit json files in Tezos-node folder

Tags: node, baking, error

I need to delete json file from Tezos node folder and can’t remember how on my MacBook

Answer (score 1):

You should find the `identity.json`, `peers.json`, `version.json` and `config.json` files under the `~/.tezos-node` directory if you did not tell Tezos to use another `data-dir` with the `--data-dir` command option.
Here, `~/` stands for your home directory. The `config.json` file may not be present.

Comment: Cant find the directory on MacBook. Do I use terminal to delete or can I delete from finder on MacBook

Comment: It is an hidden directory (starting with a dot). If you want to find it using Finder you will need to ask Finder to show the hidden files/directories.